# How to make image interact with mouse on mouse hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a website and i am stuck here. This is what i made so far

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
}


/*Container*/

.container {
  max-width: 1349px;
  margin: auto
}

.hero-image {
  background-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_flwr.gif), url("https://www.w3schools.com/howto/photographer.jpg");
  height: 350px;
  background-position: right bottom, center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
  background-size: 160px, cover;
  position: relative;
}

.hero-text {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
}

.hero-text h1 {
  font-size: 5vw;
}

.hero-text button {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  color: black;
  background-color: #ddd;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hero-text button:hover {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="hero-image">
    <div class="hero-text">
      <h1>I am John Doe</h1>
      <p>And I'm a Photographer</p>
      <button>Hire me</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <p>Page Content..</p>

</div>
```

I want to make the small flower image to move on mouse hover, i want it to interact with mouse same as this website [zooskopje.com.mk](http://zooskopje.com.mk) that does it with those images that pop up in the slider. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at `transform: translate` in css. but you need to use JS too to get the expected result

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please take some time to read the posting guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Forget JavaScript. Do it with CSS.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_overlay.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
.media-body:hover {
  animation: move 10s .2s (ease or linear) 1;
}

@keyframes move {
  from { top: 0; left: 0; }
  to   { top: -20px; left: -20px; }
}
```

Here is a fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/9dLd1fav/

This is just an example, you will need to tweak it to fit your needs.
See [CSS Animations](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)